# vscode slows extremely when multiply instances running

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, instances

Single running visual studio code works for me rapidly that I enjoyed this editor so much. However when I open another one instance both are slow as a turtle. Is there maybe a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e got mine working well with up to 4 instances on one laptop.
which platform are you using? windows?

if you really want to solve this you should make some tests to find the resource being hogged using PStools. Otherwise it can be really hard to troubleshoot:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon